# Word - Excel Mail Merge Conditional Formatting

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, conditional-formatting

I'd like to mail merge student scores from Excel to Word.  In addition I'd like to format the scores by color (IF <10 then dark red, IF >11 but <30 light red, IF >31 but <50 dark green, etc).  I've figured out the Alt F9 portion but can't figure out the code with this many variations.  Any suggestions?

An alternative could be to keep it all in Excel but using that method I can't figure out how to merge the scores by individual student in to a separate sheet that's set up with conditional formatting.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Select all cells having scores.

Menu - Home - conditional formatting - Manage Rules

This screen opens, but there are no rules at present.

[image: screen 1]

Define these 3 rules together, don't close the window or change the selection before you have defined all three.

[image: screen 2]

[image: screen 3]

[image: screen 4]

Now the screen will look like the first image aboe in which three rules are appearing. OK to close. you can unselect.

Ask if anything was not clear

Answer (score 0):

I can see that 4 years passed from your question, but now I am having the same struggle. Did you mange to find solution for your question and can you maybe explain how did you made yours  conditional formatting?

Thanks!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).